# MySQL JOIN and group by so there is one ID per row

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Two tables: products, all IDs are unique, and stock, where there can be same ID several times. I need to compare the quantities where the quantity in product table doesn't match the total quantity in the stock table.

products

```
ID     quantity
1      4
2      6
3      2
```

stock:

```
ID     quantity
1      1
1      3
2      5
3      2
```

How can I get a result where there is a single ID per row? Expected result:

```
ID     quantity as products     quantity as stock

2      6                        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a subquery that computes the total stocks, and `LEFT JOIN` it to your `products` table:

```
SELECT
    products.ID, 
    products.quantity    AS `quantity as products`, 
    total_stock.quantity AS `quantity as stock`
FROM
    products
    LEFT JOIN
    -- We compute total quantities from `stock`
    (SELECT
        stock.ID, sum(stock.quantity) AS quantity
    FROM
        stock
    GROUP BY
        stock.ID
    ) AS total_stock 
    ON total_stock.ID = products.ID
WHERE
    -- We want to find only discrepancies.
    -- We use NOT <=> to safely check nulls.
    NOT (total_stock.quantity <=> products.quantity)
ORDER BY
    products.ID ;
```

I've assumed this schema (with a `REFEFENCES` constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE stock
(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products(ID),
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;
```

You can find your example data (together with a few extra data to care for *nulls*) and this solution at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0e97d1bfaaa0f3ff6cf7cea9f2dedeb6)*

---

You can also change the `WHERE` clause to:

```
    -- We use coalesce to convert nulls to 0 (we assume *don't know* means *don't have*)
    coalesce(total_stock.quantity,0) <> coalesce(products.quantity, 0)
```

depending on your use-case.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d29694c88855f471ff1bdcac78cdd223)*

---

References:

- MySQL [NULL-safe equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)
- MySQL [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! Saved ma quite a bit of time.

Comment: The query works fine. But not sure what the '-- We use NOT <=> to safely check nulls.' means. I ran into situation where the id_product is in one table but not in the other, i.e. NULL, and it is not showing it.
Context: one table is our online shop with available quantities which are available to buy, the other table is manually checked actual stock. So I need to remove the products not actually in stock from sale.